# Avoid multiple web service access. How to achieve that?

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-8, winrt-xaml, async-await

I am trying to implement a simple Windows 8 C# XAML application where there are two calls made to access single web service one from project to load and display data and other to display notification.
Since there are two calls made for same web service I want that if one call is already made to the service the other call should wait and use the same response from the first call.

How can i achieve this kind of functionality? I have not added any code since there is no code that i have written for this. I am just trying to think first and then will I code.

Please let me know I can get some help for this kind of project structure?

Comment: Please don't stack your title with tags, it isn't necessary.

Comment: Is the response content the same on both calls?

Comment: @Alex: yes the response is same for both the calls.

Comment: So, why don't you persist the information from the first call and reuse it? Is the second call really necessary? Does it contain any different metadata which you need to use?

Comment: @Alex: That a good idea. But I am talking about a situation where both the calls are almost one after the other and the data from the first call has still not been received?

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what is the relation between the two calls? Do you know that the second call will be always after the first one started downloading? Do you want to download the response again if the first call already finished?

Comment: Detail description: 1. There are two web service call first call is to show the list of new updated books and second call I am making from pull notification which again show the new updated books one after the other. 2. The first call is made once at the start of the project and on refresh from the user 3. the second call is a pull notification that pulls data after every 10 mins and shows the notification. I am talking about a situation when the first call is made at start of the project or on refresh and then only the pull notification calls the service. How can i avoid this?

Comment: How can I avoid two calls to be made from one web service and try to use the data from which so ever is the first call made. Either that be Pull notification or List data?

Comment: @svick: The description is as mentioned above. As for your questions: 1. The relationship between two calls is only that they use the same service call and data. 2. No its not necessary that first call is always before the other any call can be made first. 3. No if the second call is made when the first is in pipeline then we will use the data of the first response else if the first call is already finished and then the second call is made then we will download the data again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by caching the `Task` that's currently downloading and not starting the download again if there is a cached `Task`:

```
private volatile Task<string> m_cachedWebServiceTask;

async Task<string> AccessWebServiceAsync()
{
    var task = m_cachedWebServiceTask;

    if (task == null)
        task = m_cachedWebServiceTask = DownloadFromWebServiceAsync();

    try
    {
        return await task;
    }
    finally
    {
        m_cachedWebServiceTask = null;
    }
}
```

Note that this code has a race condition: if you call `AccessWebServiceAsync()` twice at the same time, there is a small chance `DownloadFromWebServiceAsync()` will be called twice too. But since this in only an optimization, I think that shouldn't be a problem. If it is a problem for you, you would need to guard the access to the field by a lock.

Answer (score 0):

As I had the feeling that this problem needs further attention and it's solution could still be optimized, I decided to post another approach. The OP is mostly a problem about leveraging the following 3 scopes of requirements: **user experience** within the application, the **application's internal requirements** and the **web service's loading** with multiple requests.

1. The **application** needs to make an initial request to load the data.
2. When he asks for it, **the user expects** to get the results with the latest updates.
3. On the other side, it makes no initiate a **large series of calls to the web service** within *a very short moment of time*.

So, managing what happens in this *very short moment of time* it's actually the solution to the problem.

On the client side, the `Service1Client` class:

```
public partial class Service1Client
{
    // default time buffer value
    int _timeBuffer = 100;

    // a time buffer used for returning the same response  
    public int TimeBuffer
    {
        get { return _timeBuffer; }
        set { _timeBuffer = value; }
    }
    // the start and end time of the web service request
    static DateTime _start, _end;

    // a volatile static variable to store the response in the buffering time
    volatile static string _response;

    // used for blocking other threads until the current thread finishes it's job
    object _locker = new object();

    public async Task<string> GetResponseData()
    {
        return await Task.Factory.StartNew<string>(() =>
        {
            lock (_locker)
            {
                if (DateTime.Now >= _end.AddMilliseconds(TimeBuffer))
                {
                    _start = DateTime.Now;
                    var async = GetDataAsync();
                    _response = async.Result;
                    _end = DateTime.Now;
                }
            }
            return _response;
        });
    }
}
```

The console application used for testing:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var client = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
            client.TimeBuffer = 150;
            Console.WriteLine(client.GetResponseData().Result);
            if (Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

As a remark, note that, for the reason of a clear sample, I decided to change the returned type of the `GetDate` WCF service's method from `DateTime` to `string`.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    string GetData();
}

public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public string GetData()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        return DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: The point of `async`-`await` is to not block threads. And this solution doesn't block the main thread, but it does block one or more ThreadPool threads while the operation is executing. That's not a good approach.

Answer (score -1):

For your scenario, a feasible idea would be to extend the service class.

The `IService1` interface definition:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    DateTime GetData();
}
```

The `Service1` class definition:

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public DateTime GetData()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        return DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

On the client side, extend the `Service1Client` class definition and add a new method:

```
public partial class Service1Client
{
    static bool _isOpen;

    static DateTime? _cachedResponse;
    object _locker = new object();

    public DateTime GetResponseData()
    {
        if (!_isOpen)
        {
            if (!_cachedResponse.HasValue)
            {
                lock (_locker)
                {
                    _isOpen = true;
                    _cachedResponse = GetData();
                    _isOpen = false;
                }
                return _cachedResponse.Value;
            }
            else
            {
                Task.Factory.StartNew<DateTime>(() =>
                {
                    lock (_locker)
                    {
                        _isOpen = true;
                        _cachedResponse = GetData();
                        _isOpen = false;
                    }
                    return _cachedResponse.Value;
                });
            }
        }
        return _cachedResponse.Value;
    }
}
```

Test it:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var client = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
            Console.WriteLine(client.GetResponseData());
            if (Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work, you return from `GetResponseData()` before the result can be set (and the value returned from the `Task` doesn't have any effect). Also, the question was tagged async-await and that's what you should always use when accessing external services in Win 8 apps.

Comment: @svick, this woks in my tests.

Comment: They way you're written it, it can't work. And when I test your code, it actually doesn't work (it prints out `1.1.0001 0:00:00` for me).

Comment: You are right, I've updated the implementation. In the original answer I was focused on recurrent calls, I was not giving attention to the first call. Also, if you want to test it again, make sure that the WCF service is available.

Comment: So, if the value was retrieved previously, you start retrieving it again, but return the old value? Why? Also, this still doesn't use `async`-`await`, so it's not the right way to do it in a Windows 8 app.